# Using RxJS Observable to change css class on drag events

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

HI my goal is to use Observable sequence to listen to dragEnter/dragleave events to change css classes. IE :

```
var myDraggableListEl = document.querySelector....

var itemDragIn$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(myDraggableListEl, 'dragenter').map((e)=> e.target);

var itemDragOut$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(myDraggableListEl, 'dragleave').map((e)=> e.target);
```

Basically I just want to add a 'hover' class on 'dragenter',and then remove the same class on dragleave.

I was wondering if there was a clever way to 'merge' these 2 so that the subscription would just be something like:

```
.subscribe( (boolAdd, className, target ) => {
   boolAdd ?  target.classlist.add(className): target.classlist.remove(className)
}
```

Maybe Im just overthinking this andI  just leave the two observables as separate, but just wondering if anyone had accomplished this or if they had a better way.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can totally do this using the `Rx.Observable.merge()` method.

Links:

- [merge - general rx](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html)
- [merge - rxjs example](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/merge.md)

Example (Here's the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cb5y0p8w/)):

```
Rx.Observable.merge(
    Rx.Observable.fromEvent($el, 'dragenter').map(function(e) {
        return { target: e.target, isAdd: true, className: 'dragg' }
    }),
    Rx.Observable.fromEvent($el, 'dragleave').map(function(e) {
        return { target: e.target, isAdd: false, className: 'dragg' }
    }))
    .subscribe(function(obj){
        if(obj.isAdd) {
            obj.target.classlist.add(obj.className);
        } else {
            obj.target.classlist.remove(obj.className);
        }
    });
```

Although please consider that the following is probably much more readable:

```
    // addClass and removeClass are defined somewhere (can represent jquery's functions)
    Rx.Observable
        .fromEvent($el, 'dragenter')
        .subscribe(function(e){
            addClass(e.target, 'dragg');
        });

    Rx.Observable
        .fromEvent($el, 'dragleave')
        .subscribe(function(e){
            removeClass(e.target, 'dragg');
        });
```

Comment: Can you add the plunkr?

Comment: @Gary added a jsfiddle :)

Comment: i am trying the merge using scroll and click events seems to break the code.